# NULL MySQL to PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm looking for and don't find what's the value in PHP of *NULL* from MySQL got with PDO.
I found about *PDO::PARAM_NULL* but it's to insert data in MySQL and about constants *PDO::NULL_NATURAL*, *PDO::NULL_EMPTY_STRING* & *PDO::NULL_TO_STRING* but not about what's it for.
Example of code:

```
class CountryManager{
    public function getAll() {
        $countries = [ ];

        $query = $this->_db->query ( "SELECT f_id, f_icon, f_name FROM t_country ORDER BY f_name;" );

        while ( $data = $query->fetch ( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) )
            $countries [] = new CountryObject ( $data );

        return $countries;
    }
}
```

With CountryObject

```
class CountryObject {
    private $_f_id;
    private $_f_icon = null;
    private $_f_name;
}
```

I need to know if the nullable field f_icon is filled or not, and for all my nullable fields in my db as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value in PHP of NULL from MySQL you get with PDO is `null`.

I suppose you are just instantiating your object wrong way. Let me suggest you my article, [Fetching objects with PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/objects), which can prove thatboth PDO and mysql always return nulls all right:

```
class CountryObject {
    private $_f_id;
    private $_f_icon = null;
    private $_f_name;
}
$obj = $pdo->query("SELECT 1 as _f_id, null as _f_icon, 'name' as _f_name")
           ->fetchObject('CountryObject');
var_dump($obj);
```

returns

```
object(CountryObject)#4 (3) {
  ["_f_id":"CountryObject":private]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["_f_icon":"CountryObject":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_f_name":"CountryObject":private]=>
  string(4) "name"
}
```

Comment: Are you sure, because, I forgot, but I made a var_dump on the return value to see what I had and for a record with the f_icon as *NULL* I had a 0 (don't remember if it was string or int).

Comment: You don't need to ask whether I am sure or not. Just run this code and see yourself.

Comment: Sorry, all my fault, it probably was a mistake elsewhere, I tested your code and other things and I effectively have a null value.

Comment: Yeah. Getting numbers could be tricky but nulls are always there.

Comment: And thanks for your article, it will simplify my code.

Comment: Glad it helped! Feel free to ask if you will have any other questions!